# Pi 2: External HDD Randomly goes into Read Only File System Mode

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, filesystem, readwrite

I've a `raspberry pi 2bplus` and I've installed the latest Raspbian strectch on it. I've connected External HardDrive to the pi.

I'm running into a really weird problem that doesn't make sense to me but that's probably because of my lack of knowledge related to Linux systems.

*I've plex installed on the pi. Plex can detect & read the contents of the disk.*

The problem is when the pi boots up, the external drive is read write filesystem and therefore I can create, delete and copy files on the disk however as soon as a software for example like Firefox or Megatools tries to write something on the external disk, it can't write to the disk & it complains that the file system is Read only file system.

The disk is in good health.

I've tried downloading stuff like `sudo megadl "the url"` on the external harddrive but I still get the same error.

Why does my external drive suddenly change into read only file system when a software tries to write something on it? How can I fix this?

**PS: After firefox/megatools fails with the error mentioned above, I can no longer write/delete contents off of the external disk**

**Specs:**

*Intenso 4TB harddrive. The disk for ext3 formatted.*

Comment: `raspberry pi 2plus` so, one that does not exist? or is that what they are calling the 2 with the CPU from the 3?

Comment: `I can create, delete and copy files` - that's done using software. It sounds like a permissions issue, except that you say running `sudo somedowloader blah` also fails .... check the output of `dmesg` once the drive fails to be writable for any error messages regarding the drive

Comment: I understand however once I get this error message, I can no longer create/copy/delete files off of the external drive

Comment: yes, but is there any error or message in the output of `dmesg` that may help you determine the problem you are having with your hardware

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of the command `findmnt /mnt/myusbdrive` (or what your name and mountpoint is) two times, one time direct after reboot and one time when it seems to be read only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was some sort of OS glitch or incompatibility. I ran the following commands overnight and it fixed the problem

`sudo umount /dev/sda1 # /dev/sda1 is the name of my external drive partition`

`sudo fsck -Cy /dev/sda1`

Comment: I ran into the same issue but am wondering if there'd be a way for fsck to run on boot before USB drives are mounted?